# Safari adding class after page goes to url, not 'on click'

Tags: jquery, css, animation, click

A page here: http://berlinbraves-pub.webflow.io/

When you click the 'article' links (the large horizontal images) on the homepage, the text is meant to change to the 'category colour' on click, allowing he user to see the colour briefly before the page moves to the specified URL. This can be seen successfully on Chrome.

On Safari however, the interaction isn't visible on 'click'. It's only visible, when you go back to the page (by backspacing, etc), and then the article's text is permanently in the colour specified (no longer in the White/Black colour, but now Green, etc)

The css is here:

```
<style> 
  .footballclassed.activecolor *{ color:#88d388 !important; } 
  .basketballclassed.activecolor *{ color:#5488cc !important; } 
  .Baseballclassed.activecolor *{ color:#efc15b !important; } 
  .Runningclassed.activecolor *{ color:#6e7783 !important; } 
  .footer-content .article-title{ color:#000 !important; } 
</style>
```

The Jquery is here:

```
$( ".w-dyn-items .w-dyn-item" ).each(function() { 
  if($(this).find('.article-title').html()=='Football'){ 
    $(this).addClass("footballclassed"); } 
  if($(this).find('.article-title').html()=='Basketball'){ 
    $(this).addClass("basketballclassed"); } 
  if($(this).find('.article-title').html()=='Baseball'){ 
    $(this).addClass("Baseballclassed"); } 
  if($(this).find('.article-title').html()=='Running'){ 
    $(this).addClass("Runningclassed"); } }); 
  $( ".w-dyn-item" ).click(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("activecolor"); 
});
```

How can you make it function on Safari in the same way it does on Chrome?

Comment: is this working fine on iOS??

Comment: xcode isn't functioning here - I cannot tell.

Comment: can u try by adding cursor:pinter; to that perticular div/class. bcz i also faced some clicking problem in ios and safari, i did that and it works for me.

Comment: add 'cursor:pointer' to the .article-title div?

Comment: yes u can try for that.. unfortunately i am unable to open ur website in my office network,thatsy not getting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery click behavior is fighting with the standard html behavior and it's just not going to win. That's why you see a lot of preventDefault() on click behaviors.
Is there a reason why you can't apply the color using the :active  pseudoclass in css? Make the clickable element an , the expected and accessible element for something exhibiting the behavior of click-me-change-color-and-redirect.
.mycategory:active  {color: green;}